# XGBClassifier fit with pyspark dataframe?

Tags: pyspark, xgboost

Is it possible to pass a pyspark dataframe to a XGBClassifer as:

```
from xgboost import XGBClassifer
model1 = XGBClassifier()
model1.fit (df.select(features), df.select('label'))
```

If not, what is the best way to fit a pyspark dataframe to xgboost?

Many thanks

Answer (score 1):

I believe there are two ways to skin this particular cat.
You can either:

1. Move your `pyspark` dataframe to `pandas` using the `toPandas()` method (or even better, using `pyarrow`). `pandas` dataframes will work just fine with`xgboost`. However, your data needs to fit in the memory, so you might need to subsample if you're working with TB or even GB of data.
2. Have a look at the `xgboost4j` and `xgboost4j-spark` packages. In the same way as `pyspark` is a wrapper using `py4j`, these guys can leverage SparkML built-ins, albeit typically for Scala-Spark. For example, the `XGBoostEstimator` from these packages can be used as a stage in SparkML `Pipeline()` object.

Hope this helps.